# Gtk.ScrolledWindow without horizontal scroll bar

Tags: python, gtk3, pygobject, scrolledwindow

Using Python and Gtk3, I have created a `Gtk.TreeView` and put it inside a `Gtk.ScrolledWindow`. I don't like horizontal scroll bars, so I removed it using the `Gtk.PolicyType.NEVER`, but now I can't resize the window in that direction.

So the question is: how can I get ride of the horizontal scroll bar and at the same time to be able to resize the window horizontally?

Any help is appreciated!

**Obs:** this is how I created the ScrolledWindow:

```
    self.scrolledwindow = Gtk.ScrolledWindow()
    self.scrolledwindow.set_policy(Gtk.PolicyType.NEVER,
                                   Gtk.PolicyType.AUTOMATIC)
    self.add(self.scrolledwindow)
```

Comment: Show some code. It sounds as if you didn't set the policy of the scrolledwindow, or something.

Comment: As I said in my question, I used `Gtk.PolicyType.NEVER` for the horizontal scroll bar.

Comment: Do you mean that the window can't be re-sized horizontally *at all*, or that it can't (for instance) be more narrow than some width that might be the GtkTreeView's preferred width?

Comment: It can't be more narrow than some width. Actually, the ScrolledWindow always has the width of the wider row in the GtkTreeView. Sorry if I described my problem in a wrong way and many thanks @unwind for your help.

Comment: I finally figured it out. I assigned a fixed size to the `Gtk.CellRendererText` using `renderer_text.set_fized_size(200, -1)`. In this way I have a column whose minimum size is 200, and it is not limited anymore by the width of the wider row.

Comment: It is recommended you write your solution as answer and accept it.  In that way, other users will know this question has a valid answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**SOLUTION:**

The problem was that the window couldn't be more narrow than the wider row in the `Gtk.TreeView`, and I also wanted my window without horizontal scroll bars. The final code that solves my problem is this:

```
self.scrolledwindow = Gtk.ScrolledWindow()
self.scrolledwindow.set_policy(Gtk.PolicyType.NEVER,
                               Gtk.PolicyType.AUTOMATIC)

...

renderer_text = Gtk.CellRendererText(weight=600)
renderer_text.set_fixed_size(200, -1)
column_text = Gtk.TreeViewColumn('Name', renderer_text, text=1)
```

In that way, the `Gtk.CellRendererText` has a minimum size and can be re-sized once the window is opened.